# php syntax: switch / case with an undefined string

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this code to load any project into the page in ../content/interieur/interieur.php:

```
<ul>
<?
if (glob('content/interieur/*.txt')) {
$files = glob('content/interieur/*.{txt}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($files as $file) {

    $info = pathinfo ($file);
    $file_name = basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
    ?>

    <li class="crop"><a href="?topic=<?=$file_name?>" ><img src="content/interieur/<?=$file_name,'.jpg'?>" /></a>
    <p><?=include $file?></p>
    <hr /> 
    </li>
<? } //end foreach

} //end if 

else {?>
<li><img src="./img/404.jpg" />
<p><b>Sorry, </b>Geen projecten gevonden!</p>
</li>

<? ;} //end else

?>
```

every project should have a .txt, .jpg and .html with the same name, and then it works fine.

Next, I want to be able to click the project and load the project content with that name into the same div. In my index.php I therefore have this code:

```
<div id="mainContent">

        <?
            $files = glob('content/interieur/*.{html}', GLOB_BRACE);
            $info = pathinfo ($file);
            $file_name = basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);

            if (isset ($_GET["topic"])) {

                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    switch($_GET['topic']){
                        case $file_name: include $file; break;
                        }
                    }

                switch($_GET['topic']){                 
                    case 'home': include("content/home.html" ); break;
                    case 'werkwijze': include("content/werkwijze.html"); break;
                    (et cetera)
                    default: include("content/home.html"); break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                include("content/home.html");
            }
        ?>  


</div>
```

What I don;t get is how to combine the switch / case statements with a rule that does this for each additional project. As it is now, it doesn't return any errors, but when I click a project the div loads the default case (home.html).

So, how do I combine these into one 'switch'? I think most of the code is correct, but it probably redirects to the wrong folder, therefore maybe I need to define the 'include' command with a path (/comtent/interieur) but i don't know how that works....

have a look: http://www.wgwd.nl/bedaux and click 'projection -> interior'

Hoping this is in any way a clear question ;-)
Thx!

**EDIT:** 
thx for var_dump tip! I tried this, and the string I get back when i click "project1" is indeed 'project1', so getting the right ?topic works fine. It just doesn't refer me to 'project1.html.

So basically what I think I need is something in which the undefined case is put in together with the another ones:

```
            if (isset ($_GET["topic"])) {

                    case $file_name: include $file; break;
                    case 'home': include("content/home.html" ); break;
                    case 'werkwijze': include("content/werkwijze.html"); break;
                    (et cetera)
                    default: include("content/home.html"); break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                include("content/home.html");
            }
```

But off course that won't work

OR: the code is fine and I need to add a path, something like:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    switch($_GET['topic']){
     case $file_name: include './content/interieur/'$file; break;
    }
}
```

But I guess that syntax is wrong.....

**EDIT 2 - SOLVED:**

I got it!

Looking at the first part of the code, where I define $files and then the first switch:

```
 <?
        $files = glob('content/interieur/*.{html}', GLOB_BRACE);
        $info = pathinfo ($file);
        $file_name = basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);

        if (isset ($_GET["topic"])) {

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                switch($_GET['topic']){
                    case $file_name: include $file; break;
                    }
                }
```

I noticed I was referring to $file BEFORE it was created (is that how you put it?) in the foreach statement... So apparently when I do this:

```
        <?
            $files = glob('content/interieur/*.{html}', GLOB_BRACE);

            if (isset ($_GET["topic"])) {

                $file_included=0;
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $info = pathinfo ($file);
```

It's working fine!
Thx for the help!

Comment: Try using the php template syntax when mixing php and html: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php - In general, you should avoid mixing programm logic with html whenever possible. Look at MVC-based frameworks. They do also a lot of dirty work for you. http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Comment: Also, the <? and <?= openers could lead to serious problems on php-driven platforms < php 5.4, because webhosters turn this "short syntax" off often.

Comment: Thx for that, I'll see if I can write the code more php 4.x compatible! ... Once I sorted this out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

replace with below section

```
 $file_included=0;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        switch($_GET['topic']){
                            case $file_name: include $file;$file_included=1; break;
                            }
                        }

    if($file_included==0){
                    switch($_GET['topic']){                 
                        case 'home': include("content/home.html" ); break;
                        case 'werkwijze': include("content/werkwijze.html"); break;
                        (et cetera)
                        default: include("content/home.html"); break;
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Your code works for fine, thx for that! (Why does this work, btw?)
However, clicking the link still takes me 'home' ;-)

I edited my question, I believe it doesn't find the proper .html file because it is looking in the wrong folder, and I don't know the syntax to put a path in between 'include' and '$file'...

Comment: include('content/'.$file);    this is what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not 100% of an answer but too much text to place in a comment

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    switch($_GET['topic']){
         case $file_name: include $file; break;
    }
}
```

Firstly, a swith with one condition is basically an `if`, and in this loop both `$_GET` and `$file_name`are set outside the loop. So this comparison will either be true for all files, or for none of them. So it' really saying this:

```
if ($_GET['topic'] == $file_name) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
         include $file;
    }
}
```

Regarding the point that you always get the default "home", I would guess this is because you end up in the `default` statement. Have you tried `var_dump($_GET['topic'])` to see what's actually in there? Perhaps you are not receiving the value you are expecting.

Comment: Thx, I added the var_dump to see what I get. The outcome is as I expected, so the problem must lie elsewhere. 
I rephrased the question in the original post though.